# When Visual Studio Code starts nx console gives error "Nx Console encountered an error when activating"

Tags: nrwl-nx

Using:

- WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Visual Studio Code 1.85.2
- Nx Console 18.14.0

After Visual Studio Code starts, the following error is displayed in the output panel. As the notification indicates:

[image]

```
Telemetry: production
Nx Console encountered an error when activating
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendRequest')
    at xd (/home/x/.vscode-server/extensions/nrwl.angular-console-18.14.0/main.js:755:18088)
    at _2 (/home/x/.vscode-server/extensions/nrwl.angular-console-18.14.0/main.js:755:18254)
    at xVt (/home/x/.vscode-server/extensions/nrwl.angular-console-18.14.0/main.js:1326:2649)
    at fkn (/home/x/.vscode-server/extensions/nrwl.angular-console-18.14.0/main.js:1326:4224)
    at async l.n (/home/x/.vscode-server/bin/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:140:6255)
    at async l.m (/home/x/.vscode-server/bin/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:140:6218)
    at async l (/home/x/.vscode-server/bin/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:140:5675)
```

Comment: Resolved with Nx Console 18.14.1